# Shortcut instead of running a script every time when launching an application

Tags: linux

I had problems installing IGV (integrated genome browser). The prerequisite for that is to have installed java 11, which I have. Nonetheless, I could not make it. In the readme file of IGV, one could read that the other option would be to run the script igv.sh from the shell (./igv.sh).

It functions properly so that IGV is launched. But I find it cumbersome since I'd need the terminal, or I might forget the name of the script so that I need to look after.

Q: How can I solve this problem by making a shortcut, so that I could launch IGV directly by only clicking, or at least by only typing igv in the shell?

Comment: You can use something like [menulibre](https://bluesabre.org/projects/menulibre/) to create launcher in your system. You just have to name it and insert your path folowed by executable script or absolute path to that script.

Comment: Thanks. It seems complicated. Is there not a more direct way ? I dont need it for other applications.

Comment: Yes, you can create that launcher yourself. Have a look [here](http://xmodulo.com/create-desktop-shortcut-launcher-linux.html)